# vtk example from vtk book does not work with 9.1

Tags: c++, vtk

In the [VTK book](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/textbook/raw/master/VTKBook/VTKTextBook.pdf) at page 63 there is an example which I pasted below.

```cpp
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkCamera.h>
#include <vtkConeSource.h>
#include <vtkNamedColors.h>
#include <vtkNew.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
int main(int, char* [])
{
    vtkNew<vtkNamedColors> colors;
    vtkNew<vtkConeSource> cone;
    cone->SetHeight(3.0);
    cone->SetRadius(1.0);
    cone->SetResolution(10);
    vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> coneMapper;
    coneMapper->SetInputConnection(cone->GetOutputPort());
    vtkNew <vtkActor> coneActor;
    coneActor->SetMapper(coneMapper);
    vtkNew <vtkRenderer > ren1;
    ren1->AddActor(coneActor);
    ren1->SetBackground(
        colors->GetColor3d("MidnightBlue").GetData());
    vtkNew <vtkRenderWindow > renWin;
    renWin->AddRenderer(ren1);
    renWin->SetSize(300, 300);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 360; ++i)
    {
        // render the image
        renWin->Render();
        // rotate the active camera by one degree
        ren1->GetActiveCamera()->Azimuth(1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have downloaded and compiled VTK 9.1 on my Windows 10 machine. I tried to run the example as it is and it crashes on the following line:

```cpp
    ren1->SetBackground(
        colors->GetColor3d("MidnightBlue").GetData());
```

The culprit is actually the call to `colors->GetColor3d("MidnightBlue").GetData()`. Since I do not care what color the background is at this very early point, I replaced the crashing line with

```cpp
    ren1->SetBackground(0.20, 0.20, 0.20);
```

Now it runs to the end, but no window shows up. My expectation was that a window would pop up with a rotating cone inside. No such luck. Can anybody point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to try this: [https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Cone/](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Cone/)

Comment: I just successfully tested that example with vtk-9.0.2 using vcpkg to provide vtk binaries. I used the CMakeLists.txt and the Cone.cxx file with Visual Studio 2019 16.7.19. I use these specific versions for both because my versions must match work / production code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try using CMake. In my original post I forgot to mention that I created my own Visual Studio project avoiding CMake. But if it works with CMake, I guess that's the route I will take.